# When you cast alarm, is the password also spoken?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

The [alarm](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/alarm) spell

> Alarm creates a subtle ward on an area you select. Once the spell effect is in place, it thereafter sounds a mental or audible alarm each time a creature of Tiny or larger size enters the warded area or touches it. A creature that speaks the password (determined by you at the time of casting) does not set off the alarm. You decide at the time of casting whether the alarm will be mental or audible in nature.

So the password is chosen at the time of casting, but do you need to speak the password during casting or is it something that is chosen mentally? The reason I ask is if someone is watching, they could learn the password if it is spoken at the time of casting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't say you speak it as part of the verbal components. Ergo it's not spoken as part of the verbal components.

There's no reason to believe that the password has to be spoken for any other reason either, as it doesn't say it is spoken aloud as part of the spell effect like other spells do (like [*suggestion*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/suggestion.html#suggestion) or [*command*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/command.html#command)).

Comment: I agree with this. Although I'm sure a DM _could_ rule that the password is spoken, that would be a significant nerf to the spell, as anyone nearby would know the password.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a spell which does require having that as part of the casting?

Comment: @Fering I've update the answer. None that I can recall that specify as part of the V component, but I added two examples that do indicate something that is spoken aloud as part of the effect.